# Ravendb 960 does not honor JsonIgnore with property of Dictionary<string, object>

Tags: json.net, ravendb

Does JsonIgnore not work when a property has data?  I have the followin class:

```
public class SomeObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public List<string> ErrorList { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public Dictionary<string, object> Parameters { get; set; }

        public SomeObject()
        {
            this.ErrorList = new List<string>();
            this.Parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }
    }
```

My expectation was that JsonIgnore would exclude properties from De- / Serialization.  My RavenDB document has data.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using any of the 1.2 (unstable) builds, you'll need to use the copy of `JsonIgnoreAttribute` that's in `Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json`.  All of Json.Net has been internalized.

The better approach would to not expose your parameters dictionary directly via a property, since you don't want it serialized.  Perhaps a pattern like the following would suffice:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
public Dictionary<string, object> GetParameters()
{
    return _parameters;
}
```

Personally, I try not to bring any external dependency into my domain objects, so I like to avoid things like `[JsonIgnore]` anyway.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I just saw in your title the 960 version.  You may be encountering a different issue, which is that 960 relies on Json.Net 4.0.8.  You may have better luck with the 972 client at http://nuget.org/packages/RavenDB.Client/1.0.972.  Still, I think the better advice is to restructure to avoid needing it at all.

Comment: +1 Thanks Matt - I'm going with your restructuring advice.  I'd go with 972 but that has issues with RESTSharp, the Auth bundle, etc.  The Json.net 4.0.8 is a real pain when you start to add additional components.

Comment: You should also consider the latest 1.2 release.  It's significantly better than the 1.0 builds.  From what I understand, it is very close to stable release, so if you're going to be in development for awhile, it's a better choice IMHO.

Comment: I've been debating when to switch - I have something I want to finish and get into peoples' hands soon.  Have you had any experience with it?

Comment: I switched to 1.2 a long time ago and have had very few issues.  But I'm still in development phase, so I can't speak from a production POV.  However, I understand RavenHQ runs on 1.2 now, and others are using it as well.  Probably best to ask on the RavenDB Google Group.